# How to search a string in a file?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to read all the files within the folder.

Below is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for %%I in (C:\test\*.print_job.*) do (
   Set Name=%%~nxI
   echo !Name!
)
pause
```

I am able to get all the .print_job files but now I want to read all the files and look for a specific identifier.

- if the file contains "MOUNT" then move that file to C:\Folder1
- if the    file contains "PROD" then the file should get moved to
  C:\Folder2
- if    the file contains "SPI" then the file should get moved to
  C:\Folder3

Thanks in advance

Comment: What didn't you understand about my advice in your previous question?  Which you deleted and had lots of good information.  Not a big fan of that.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you meant to ask `if the file contains`? or did you mean `if the file name contains`?

Comment: Hi compo.. I am trying to read each file and trying to get a specific unique keyword that each file contains. That's why i have written that if a file data contains a keyword mount then do this and that and so on

Comment: @Roy, I'm aware of what you wrote, thank you. I asked for clarificatioin because you currently have two answers below and both of them saw it differently!

Comment: @Roy, the difference between the keyword `mount` and the keyword `MOUNT` is quite important where case sensitivity applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem             string  target                  destination
call :movefiles "MOUNT" "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder1"
call :movefiles "PROD"  "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder2"
call :movefiles "SPI"   "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder3"
goto :eof

:movefiles
if not exist "%~3" md "%~3"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('2^>nul findstr /l /m /c:"%~1" "%~2"') do (
    move "%%~A" "%~3"
)
goto :eof
```

Use of `call :movefiles` to handle each of the 3 strings to
search for in the target files.

Call syntax: `call :movefiles <string> <target> <destination>`

Makes the destination directory if not exist. If string found
in a target file, the file will be moved into the destination
folder.

The `findstr` arguments used are:

- `/l` Uses search strings literally.
- `/m` Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
- `/c:string` Uses specified string as a literal search string.

You can insert `rd "%~3"` after the `for` loop if you want to
remove empty destination folders.

---

To loop every 2 seconds:

```
@echo off
:main
rem             string  target                  destination
call :movefiles "MOUNT" "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder1"
call :movefiles "PROD"  "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder2"
call :movefiles "SPI"   "C:\test\*.print_job.*" "C:\Folder3"
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
goto :main

:movefiles
if not exist "%~3" md "%~3"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('2^>nul findstr /l /m /c:"%~1" "%~2"') do (
    echo move "%%~A" "%~3"
)
goto :eof
```

You may need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the script as it is in a continuous loop.

If you can use a task scheduler instead then that could work.

Comment: Hi Macheal. Thanks for the reply. But the above command never reads the seconds line. It always searches the first condition and then exits.

Comment: @Roy, try changing `@echo off` to `@echo on` and see if all 3 calls are working. It displays OK for me so perhaps you do not have the strings in the read files or some other possible issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. It was me who was doing it wrong. I was trying to run this job every 2 seconds so I used goto with time delay which is causing it to only execute the first condition.. How can I continuously run the above batch job?

Comment: @Roy, updated answer with a loop with 2 second timeout.

Comment: @Michael- I tried the updated solution but after moving the files it is always giving exception as FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\test\*.print_job.*. How can I not have this exception?

Comment: Added `2^>nul` to `findstr` to not output the error message of not finding file matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. I am a novice in Batch Scripting and needed to do this work cause by bosses wanted me to. You saved me.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If a file name with the search word removed is different it had been in there.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (C:\test\*) do Call :Sub "%%I"
Pause
Goto :Eof
:Sub
Set "Name=%~nx1"
if "%Name%" neq "%Name:MOUNT=%" (move "%~1" "C:\Folder1\" & Goto :Eof)
if "%Name%" neq "%Name:PROD=%"  (move "%~1" "C:\Folder2\" & Goto :Eof)
if "%Name%" neq "%Name:SPI=%"   (move "%~1" "C:\Folder3\" & Goto :Eof)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response LotPings. I don't have much expertise in Batch Scripting but I am trying to re execute the entire command again and I am using Goto command at the end. But the for loop always reads the first filename always..